# RingCentral Main Company Number SMS `Phone number doesn't belong to extension` error

Tags: sms, ringcentral

I tried to send SMS and listed the `from` as our Main Company Number but it would not go out. Said `Phone number doesn't belong to extension` per the error below. The RC account I am using for running my API calls does not have a phone line/number assigned.

Do I have to be logged in with the account that matches the `from` phone number?

```json
{
  "errorCode": "FeatureNotAvailable",
  "message":  "Phone number doesn't belong to extension",
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "MSG-304",
      "message": "Phone number doesn't belong to extension"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send SMS from the Main Company Number for a single user or multiple users using the following approaches:

**Scenario 1: Send and Respond using a single user**

> In-order to send SMS from the main company number:
>
> 1. Set the Operator Extension
> 2. Authorize using the Operator Extension
> 3. Send SMS using the Main Company Number
>
> Operator Extension: When a caller presses 0 (zero) or does not enter an extension number, the system connects the call to the designated operator extension by default. An Administrator can configure the operator extension
>   to have different call handling rules.

**Scenario 2: Send and Respond using Multiple Users**

> In-order to send and SMS from Main Company Number and respond to it using multiple users, set up a call-queue and configure the operator extension to point to the Call Queue.
>
> 1. Create a Call-Queue and assign a password to it.
> 2. Set the Operator Extension to point to Call Queue.
> 3. Authorize using the Operator Extension ( Call Queue )
> 4. Send SMS using the Main Company Number

More info is available here:

https://devcommunity.ringcentral.com/ringcentraldev/topics/how-to-send-sms-from-the-main-company-number

To verify the numbers your user extension can send SMS from, call the following endpoint:

`GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/phone-number`

This will return an array of phone numbers. Check the `features` property. The ones that can be used will have the `SMSSender` and/or `MMSSender` features. More info on this is available in the Developer Guide:

http://ringcentral-api-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messages_sms-and-pager/#listing-valid-sms-sending-numbers